# jinja2: convert string to dict object?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have a json string stored in the database and when this is pulled out and shown on the template it is a string. I want to convert this into a dict object so I can access the contents directly.

string = "{'a':1, 'b':3}"

{{ obj }} ---> string "{'a':1, 'b':3}"

{{ obj.b }} ---> I want to access it like an object.

Comment: [import json](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html)?

Comment: @bereal no I am looking for a filter to be able to convert a string into an object that I can access in the jinja template.

Comment: You can use any Python expressions in Jinja or register your own filters.

Comment: Why do you want to do this in your template as opposed to in the view that loads the value from the database?

Answer (score 0):

```
obj_in_string = "{'a':1, 'b':3}"
{{ obj_in_string | tojson }}
```

Ref: https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.tojson

Comment: Shouldn't it be `fromjson`?

Comment: This seems to convert an object into a string, not a string into an object, which seems to be what is being requested. So, this would not work.

Answer (score -6):

Write the following code in a temporary file and write a function back-end side:

```
{{ obj.b | str_to_obj }}
```

Put this code in your jinja filter file:

```
for convert str to dic object 

def str_to_obj(str):

    return eval(str)
```

And write this code in your admin file:

```
app.jinja_env.filters['str_to_obj'] = jinja_filters.str_to_obj
```

Comment: eval() is considered bad programming practice because it allows users to dynamically execute arbitrary Python code, hence the down votes. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940